# Can I change the database when using selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, iis, selenium-webdriver, iis-express

I have a main project with its database (and corresponding connection string in the web.config). Furthermore, a test project with a separate test database (and a corresponding connection string in app.config of the test project). I would like to use the test database for all the tests.

When I run selenium tests the IISExpress Server uses the "main connection string" in the web.config instead of the "test connection string" in the app.config. Is there anyway to tell the Controller is is running in test mode and to use a different connection string?

I am using the following setup to get Selenium and the IIS running:

```
    _iisProcess = new Process
   {
        StartInfo =
        {
              FileName = ....IIS Express\iisexpress.exe,
              Arguments = $"/path:\"{_applicationPath}\" /port:{_iisPort}"
        }
   };
    _iisProcess.Start();
    ChromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Perhaps I can pass a variable with the IIS Start, which I can use to change the connection string when opening the database connection?

I tried to use a global variable, but this does not work as the test and the selenium instance are running on separate instances. So the value is not passed across.

Answer (score 0):

In your unittest code simply modify the web.config using `XmlDocument` then revert it back.